# Pinvoke cdecl convention with char**

Tags: c#, c++, char, pinvoke

In summary:
I`m trying to use a C++ dll with **cdecl calling convention** all ran fine unless i get to this method signature:

```
int SaveToBuffer( char **buf, int *buf_size );
```

from what i have read i should use it like this:

```
    [DllImport("entry.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "SaveToBuffer")]
    private static int SaveToBuffer( ref sbyte[] buf, ref int buf_size );
```

This does not work if this function is called from C# program crashes.
I suppose this is  related to Cdecl calling model and should use Marshal.AllocHGlobal(value),
I can`t imagine how should it be done correct.

I also tryed this:

```
[DllImport("entry.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "SaveToBuffer")]
private static int SaveToBuffer( IntPtr buf, ref int buf_size );
```

And then alocate enough memory

```
  IntPtr data=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(128000);
  int bufSize=128000;
  var sCode=SaveToBuffer(data,bufSize ); /* value of scode idicate succses*/
```

Calling this way i get return value from SaveToBuffer indicating function succseeded but: bufSize returns to 0 and how should i read my data from IntPtr.

I`m completly stuck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with the calling convention. The problem is in the buffer handling.

There's really only one sensible way to interpret the C++ argument types and the apparent intent to return an array of bytes. That is that the buffer is allocated and populated by the callee, and its address returned in `buf`. The buffer length is returned in `buf_size`.

With these semantics the function arguments cannot be marshalled automatically and you'll have to do it manually:

```
[DllImport("entry.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static int SaveToBuffer(out IntPtr buf, out int buf_size);
```

Call like this

```
IntPtr buf;
int buf_size;
int retval SaveToBuffer(out buf, out buf_size);
// check retval
```

Then copy to byte array like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[buf_size];
Marshal.Copy(buf, buffer, 0, buf_size);
```

The DLL will also need to export a function to deallocate the unmanaged buffer.